# fisheye camera calibration

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am working on Fisheye camera calibration, and I'm not getting the expected result and I don't know where I'm wrong. I'm new to this camera calibration.

My Parameters from calibration

```
Focal Length:          fc = [ 410.7476   408.0925 ]
Principal point:       cc = [ 369.3690   299.0193 ]
Skew:             alpha_c = [ 0.8336 ] 
Fisheye Distortion:    kc = [ -0.3726   0.0931   0.0107   0.0000 ]
```

My code to undistort:

```
fisheye::estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(intrinsic, distCoeffs, input.size(), Matx33d::eye(), newK, 1);
fisheye::undistortImage(input, output, intrinsic, distCoeffs, newK, input.size());//Size(640,360));
```

This is my input image:

[image]

This is what I get as output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that your Result is coming from a wrong use of the undistort functions. I think, that your Camera Matrix from the Calibration is wrong. You should try that again. And don't forget, you have to take ~20 Images with your Camera also you should make sure, that you used different viewports to take the images of the chessboard or circlegrid. After That Undistort an Image and look at the Result.

I also got sometimes bad results with the camera calibration, but after a successful calibration and a good Camera Matrix everything was fine.

Even in this [Tutorial](http://aishack.in/tutorials/calibrating-undistorting-opencv-oh-yeah/) he mentions, that the calibration could give you sometimes bad results.

Comment: @VincenttheOne, I used the same camera parameters in Matlab, and The results are good...

Comment: @Venkat interesting, could you post the Result from Matlab here?

Comment: @VincenttheOne, Check this links [Input](http://imgur.com/thbgrGi) and [Output](http://imgur.com/CvdNf65). And this is the [intrinsic parameters](http://imgur.com/Ss4jQC4) that I'm using in the OpenCV, can u Check whether the order is correct... Thank you...

Comment: @Venkat I'm not that good in Camera Calibration, that I check if a result is good/bad from the parameters sorry. But the Output Image still has a pincushion effect. So probably you have to check the Calibration again.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get good results in undistortion of fisheye image without using `fisheye::estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify()` and `fisheye::undistortImage()` at all.
After obtaining K (camera matrix) and D (distortion coeffs) via `fisheye::calibrate()`, you can put them directly to `initUndistortRectifyMap()`. This will produce maps for undistorted image production via `cv::remap()`