# Why the undistorted image is with fish eye?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I used the camera calibration example code from OpenCV to calibrate the camera. Then wanted to correct the distortion on some images. I used this code to remove the distortion. It works but the fish eye view still remains. How to get the image after removing distortion without fish eye? The input image is without fish eye.

Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv\cxcore.h>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat src, gray;
    //remove distortion in the image (after calibration)
    Mat undistorted;
    //Size1280x720;
    Size imageSize(1280,720);
    cv::Mat image=imread("C:/Test/4.png");
    Mat view, rview, map1, map2;
    Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat1d(3, 3) <<  8.5033354550764898e+002, 0, 640, 0, 8.5033354550764898e+002, 360, 0, 0, 1);
    Mat distCoeffs = (Mat1d(1, 5) << -0.3, 2.8770882755049054e-001, 0, 0, -1.4405356460809188e-001);
          initUndistortRectifyMap(
                cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(),
                getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imageSize, 1, imageSize, 0), imageSize,
                CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
    // apply mapping functions
    cv::remap(image, undistorted, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR); // interpolation type
    imshow("gg",undistorted);
    while(uchar(waitKey(1))!='Q');
    return 0;
}
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to say that your image has fisheye distortion (_It works but the fish eye view still remains._)  and that it does not (_The input image is without fish eye._). Could you clarify? 

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096429/fisheye-camera-calibration).

Comment: Yes , yes correct . t works but the  output (corrected image) is with fish eye . The input image is without fish eye.